# SQL SELECT Statement for selecting data from two tables using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just tinkering with SQL as I am trying to get into more complex statements. I don't know this qualifies for it or not but please guide how to go about it.

I have looked at JOINS and some question of Multiple Select Statements but unable to understand them correctly.

I have the following two tables:

**emp table**:

```
emp_id, name, address, org_id
```

**books table**:

```
id, emp_id, status, org_id
```

where `emp_id` in books table is foreign key referencing emp table.

I need to fetch all the records from books table of a particular org. But along with that I need to get all the data of respective employee like name, address along the result.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Two org_id columns, one in each table?

Comment: His schema is not normalized properly.  But this doesn't necessarily mean the question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: It's not an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select B.*,E.name,E.address from books B
     inner join employee E 
     on B.emp_id=E.emp_id 
     where B.org_id=1;
```

I took value of of `org_id` as 1 for test purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work for you:

```
SELECT b.id, b.status, b.org_id, e.emp_id, e.name, e.address
FROM Books b LEFT JOIN Employee e
ON e.emp_id = b.emp_id
WHERE b.org_id = 100
```

This would be the query for org `100`.

It appears that your current schema is not normalized very well:

```
Employee: emp_id, name, address, org_id
Books:    id, emp_id, status, org_id
```

The two tables both store the `org_id`, which presumably means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT books.id, books.emp_id, books.status, books.org_id, emp.name, emp.address
FROM books
JOIN emp ON emp.emp_id = books.emp_id
WHERE books.org_id = '3'
```

As the other said, the `org_id` from `emp` table makes no sense. You must remove it from the table.

Answer (score 1):

if you want all records from the books table try this

```
Select b.id,c.emp_id,b.status,e.name,e.address
from emp_table e
Left join books_table b
on(e.emp_id=b.emp_id)
where e.org_id='3' and b.org_id='3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query this will gives you all book record with particular org_id along with all employee record

```
SELECT * FROM emp as e1
LEFT JOIN books as b1 ON e1.emp_id = b1.emp_id WHERE e1.org_id = 'YOUR_ID'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM emp as e1
RIGHT JOIN books as b1 ON e1.emp_id = b1.emp_id WHERE e1.org_id = 'YOUR_ID'
```

Answer (score 1):

This query might give you the results you want. You might want to learn more about **joins** in SQL. A `LEFT JOIN` gives you all records from one table, and matching records from another.

```
SELECT books.*,
    emp.name AS emp_name,
    emp.address AS emp_address,
    emp.org_id AS emp_org_id
FROM books
    LEFT JOIN emp ON books.emp_id = emp.emp_id
WHERE books.org_id=?
```

Comment: also, create indexes for emp_id and org_id

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for all recors both tables :

select * from books 
inner join emp on
 books.emp_id=emp.emp_id
 where books.emp_id=emp.emp_id